# Spring и парсинг сайтов

Tags: java, spring

Можно ли применить Spring для чтения данных с других сайтов?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Не надо замарачиваться и искать тулзы в Spring для этого есть удобный инструмент,[JSoup](https://jsoup.org/). Примеры

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```

Или же если ты хочешь body:

```
Elements body = doc.select("body");
```

Или если ты хочешь все `<а>` тэги:

```
Elements links = doc.select("body a");
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071568/parse-web-site-html-with-java)